# How to set condition for specific part in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my postgresql statement.

```
select sum("Color") as color,round(avg("Color")) as avg_color 
from "color_table"
```

How can I set the condition for avg part?

I done some study and i found `interval` seems very useful. But I dont know where to set the condition.

I just want to get the average for Color which `trandate` is in past 90 days from now.

Comment: What about the sum?  Do you also have a time restriction on the sum as well?

Comment: There is no restriction on sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Color) AS color,
    ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN trandate < NOW() - INTERVAL '90 DAYS'
                   THEN Color END)) AS avg_color 
FROM "color_table";
```

This interprets your requirement as wanting the average of records where the `trandate` is older than 90 days from now.  If instead you want *within* the last 90 days, then reverse the inequality.

If you are using Postgres 9.4 or later, you may also use the `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Color) AS color,
    ROUND(AVG(Color) FILTER (WHERE trandate < NOW() - INTERVAL '90 DAYS')) AS avg_color
FROM "color_table";
```

Comment: But when i execute it, it return error: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "as"` which point to the last `as`

Comment: @YvKl I'm not sure this error has to do with my code.

Comment: Yeah, it works with the second answer. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
 with cte as
   ( select SUM(Color) AS color,0 as avg_color 
    FROM "color_table"
    union all
    select 0, avg(Color ) FROM "color_table"
    where trandate < NOW() - INTERVAL '90 DAYS'
  ) select max(color) as color ,max(avg_color) as avg_color from cte
```